# checking if a division gives remainder 0

Tags: c++, arduino, division

hi i am writing an arduino program and i must check if a variable divided by 60 gives remainder 0. This variable is increased by 1 each second. I tried to write

```
if (variable % 60 == 0){
...
}
```

but it work even if the variable is 3, 6, 9...

my exact code is:

```
    if (millis()/1000 != prevsec){
    prevsec = millis()/1000;
    if (millis() % 60 == 0){
      Serial.print("light");
  Serial.println(analogRead(0));
  tempC = analogRead(1);           //read the value from the sensor
  tempC = (5.0 * tempC * 100.0)/1024.0;  //convert the analog data to temperature
  Serial.print("tempin");
  Serial.println((byte)tempC); 
    }
    Serial.println(millis()/1000);
  }
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong
thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be worth reading the documentation of the functions you're using. Or at least think a bit intuitively... What units do you expect a function called `millis()` return the time? Got it?

Comment: He obviously knows what units they are, since he divides by 1000 to set `prevsec`.

Comment: ok guys thanks i had just forgot to divide by 1000 to get the seconds

Comment: Also, you should avoid reading millis() multiple times since (of course) it can change between calls. Sample it once and then use the variable for the rest of the function. In your case, you can even convert to seconds once and re-use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if you are dividing by 60 a number of milliseconds. You should divide number of seconds.